# Can I block iframe from loading inside of details:not([open])?

Tags: css, iframe, youtube

This question might not have an answer. I was hoping for an easy way to keep Youtube frames from starting the loading process at all when they're inside of closed  tags.

This is ineffective:

details:not([open]) iframe { display: none; }

The browser seems to load iframe even if they are display: none. Is there a CSS trick I can try, so I don't have to use JS (which I can, but...)?

Comment: I may be wrong ( which is why i have added a comment and not an answer) but the concept that i think you are trying to achieve is know as "lazy loading" i'm assuming that the fact the videos are on the page in the first place mean you anticipate using them so you want to delay the request to fetch the video until you are ready to use it.

Comment: Try `loading="lazy"` as an attribute on your iframe in HTML. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#images_and_iframes)